# cannot use package-list-packages on macos

Tags: package, osx

Problem: cannot install packages in Emacs
what i have tried:
I have a macbook pro m2 and installed Emacs using `brew cask install` and then installed Doom Emacs. Before that tried just using normal Emacs... in both cases i cannot use `M-x package-list-packages` to list and install ...the command does not appear in spite of having `package.el` in the path inside `.emacs.d`

Comment: Can you reproduce it by `emacs -Q`?

Comment: just tried now ...same outcome...package-list-packages just does not appear as auto completion and gives `[no-match]`

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/docs/getting_started.org#where-not-to-install-emacs-from) - the cask install is not recommended, use emacs-plus instead. Also, doomemacs does not use ```packages```, so ```package-list-packages``` does not work, it is not present. The link above tell you also how to install/config doomemacs.